# Parsing JSON into CSV in Python

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm trying to parse JSON files into CSV. I've been able to get the headers of the JSON file to be output into the CSV but I can't figure out how to get the data into the file.

```
# Python program to convert
# JSON file to CSV
import json
import csv

# Opening JSON file and loading the data
# into the variable data
with open('test1.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

for i in range(len(data)):

    training_data = data[i]['profile']


    # now we will open a file for writing
    data_file = open('data_file.csv', 'w')

    # create the csv writer object
    csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file)

    # Counter variable used for writing
    # headers to the CSV file
    count = 0
    #type(training_data)

    for profile in training_data:
        if count == 0:

            header = training_data.keys()
            csv_writer.writerow(header)
            count += 1
        csv_writer.writerow(training_data.values())

    data_file.close()
```

This is the file im trying to parse
https://textdoc.co/OuphoV5saiwWYS8g

If someone could help me out I'd be eternally grateful

Comment: "but I can't figure out how to get the data into the file." **Which** data, into **what** file? **What happens** when you try your code, and **how is that different** from what is supposed to happen? Please read [ask] and [mre]. Show, **in the post itself**, a **small** example of input; and explain **exactly** what the output should contain for that input. Please also read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**; questions are to help build the site, [not to "help you"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) - which is why we expect a **question**, not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

would something like this work for you?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json(json_file)
df.to_csv('data_file.csv')
```

or for more complex nested json, you may have to load as a dictionary and manipulate:

```
data = json.loads(json_str)
data_transformed = [i for i in data['data']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data_transformed )
df.to_csv('data_file.csv')
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and don't try to guess at the question. We have no idea how the data is structured or what the desired output is, or if third-party libraries will be accepted, or what kind of manipulation might be necessary, or even really whether to treat this question as a how-to or a debugging question. (BTW: `[i for i in data['data']]` is more neatly spelled `list(data['data'])`, although `data['data']` could presumably be passed directly to `pd.DataFrame` anyway.)